# CakePHP 3.5 Translate behavior I18n::getDefaultLocale() changes by itself

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-3.0, translate

I am using CakePHP 3.5. When My browser is in english, enverything is fine. The default locale is en_US, as I set it, and I can display content in french if I set the locale to fr_CA (I18n::setLocale('fr_CA'))

But when I change my browser's language to fr_CA, it somehow changes the default locale as well to fr_CA. So the website displays in french, but the content still displays in english since it is now the default locale

Setting the default locale in config\app.php

```
'App' => [
    'namespace' => 'App',
    'encoding' => env('APP_ENCODING', 'UTF-8'),
    'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'en_US'),
    .....
],
```

Adding the valid locales in src\Application.php

```
$middlewareQueue->add(new LocaleSelectorMiddleware(['en_US', 'fr_CA']));
```

Adding the Translate behavior in ArticlesTable.php

```
$this->addBehavior('Translate', [
    'fields' => ['name', 'slug'],
    'allowEmptyTranslations' => false,
]);
```

Fetching the content in ArticlesController.php

```
$query = $this->Articles->find('all')
    ->where(['Articles.name !=' => ''])
    ->contain(['Media' => function ($q) {
        return $q->find('medium');
}]);
```

When my browser is in english (en_US) and I echo I18n::getDefaultLocale()

```
'en_US'
```

When it's in french (fr_CA) and I echo I18n::getDefaultLocale();

```
'fr_CA'
```

Note that I updated to CakePHP 3.5 recently and followed the guide to add the Middleware:
[Adding the new HTTP Stack to an Existing Application](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html#adding-http-stack)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bug that will be fixed in the next release (`3.5.3`).

See **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/11200**

Until this is fixed you can either apply the patch locally on own your own, or manually invoke `\Cake\I18n\I18n::getDefaultLocale()` once in your bootstrap so that the default locale is being stored before the modifications of the locale selector are being aplied.